# Crash when CFRelease(CFArrayRef)

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook, core-foundation

I have method which is clear the adress book in the device.
the method is below.

```
-(void) clearAdressBook
{
    ABAddressBookRef addrBook=ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef groups = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(addrBook);
    if(groups)
    {
        CFIndex numGroups = CFArrayGetCount(groups);
        for(CFIndex idx=0; idx<numGroups; ++idx)
        {
            ABRecordRef groupItem = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(groups, idx);

                CFArrayRef people=
                ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers(groupItem);
                if(people)
                {
                    CFIndex peopleCount=CFArrayGetCount(people);
                    for(CFIndex ind=0;ind<peopleCount;++ind)
                    {
                        ABRecordRef person=CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, ind);
                        ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(addrBook, person, nil);
                        ABAddressBookSave(addrBook, NULL);
                        CFRelease(person);
                    }
                    CFRelease(people);//CRASH
                }

            }
        }

    CFRelease(groups);
}
```

when I'm releasing CFArrayRef application crashes, what is wrong here? As i know i have to release all objected returned from CF methods which names contains copy or create right ?

Comment: Hmm. According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABGroupRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers), it says it returns the array, so maybe it's already autoreleased? Do you get a memory leak if you don't release the people?

Comment: profiler shows that everything is ok, and there is no memory leak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably over-releasing here the "person" object. Infact person is retrieved from an array and it follows the "get rule" so you're not the owner of it and you cannot release it (or: you can first retain it and then release it if you're not sure of the object life span). At the end of the for-loop when you release "people", the array tries to release its internal objects ("people") which have been over-releases and this leads to the crash.

So try to remove the CFRelease(people) statement or, as extra safety, add a CFRetain(people) immediately after you fetch person from the array (but then don't remove the CFRelease(people) instruction).

Comment: I didn't even notice that. Good catch.

Comment: I have removed CFRelease(person); and put back CFRelease(people); now it works fine. thanks.

Comment: I know it was 2 years ago but thanks for this helpful hint.  I couldn't figure out my crash until I saw that "over-releasing" is a thing... my problem was releasing after using getMatchingServices() ..